# google javascript spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make function that tells me how many there are words that contains less than 3 letters. 
For example, "Tomorrow will be rain. So bring your umbrellas"
in this sentence,  only "be" and "so" so equal two. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function (stri){

return ("less than 3 ").length;

}
```

( I am aiming to use \w (regular expression) if its possible.)

Comment: My understanding of java-script is low.  I want to make this function so I click script managers and create a new sheet.  I want to name this function Letter2. therefore, I start with making a function name. function letter2 (words){ return ( "less than 3").length; but when I create this on java script it says dimiss.

Answer (score 1):

If you use lodash you can do the following...

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // create a function to call with your string and the min size of the word
    function countSmalls(s,min) {

      // split by non word characters
      return _.where(s.split(/\W/),function(v,i,l){

        // return true or false to satisfy the callback, all *truthy* values are added to the return value of _.where
        return v && v.length < min;
      }).length;
    }

    // create some text
    var lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

    // call your function
    countSmalls(lorem,3); // 24 (words that are < 3 characters)

</script>
```

Comment: It's a utility library that helps you manipulate collections and much more... Check it out :) http://lodash.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. I must look them. it seems very helpful. is there any simple way to create function?

Comment: You could loop over s.split(/\W/) and test each value manually adding small words to an array or incrementing a counter... I like the simplicity of Chad's solution, but the regexp /\w/g is counting non-word characters, so it won't work as is.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function countSmallWords(stringToTest){
  var smallWords = /\b\w{1,2}\b/g;
  return stringToTest.match(smallWords).length;
}
```

Explanation: It uses the regular expression `\b\w{1,2}\b` with the global flag to match all words in a string that are one or two characters. Then it uses the match function on that string to give an array of the words. Finally, get the length property for the count.

Example usage:

```
//Example 1:
alert(countSmallWords("Tomorrow will be rain. So bring your umbrellas"));
//alerts 2

//Example 2:
var smallWordCount = countSmallWords("Hello. What a nice day it is.");
//smallWordCount == 3

//Example 3:
var smallWordCount = countSmallWords("Are there any small words in this sentence?");
console.log(smallWordCount);
//Press F12 and you will see 1 in the browser console.
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't not work or i might misunderstanding. is it necessary to add function name in the top of vars? \w means any alphanumeric character right?

Comment: Right, just define your function and then call it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes, I was aiming to use regular expression. your hit is very helpful. I want to confirm that I open up the scrip manager on google spreadsheet, then add function findSmallWords( var findSmallWords = function(stringToTest){
  var smallWords = / \w{1,2} /g;
  return stringToTest.match(smallWords).length;
}  once I created this, I go on spreadsheet then type =findSmallWords

Comment: also where do i put alert(findSmallWords("Tomorrow will be rain. So bring your umbrellas")); I am not sure how "alert" command use in java script

Comment: /*this is I wrote down on script, it gave me error, when i tried on spreadsheet */                                                          function finds(){
  
     var findSmallWords = function(stringToTest){
     var smallWords = / \w{1,2} /g;
     return stringToTest.match(smallWords).length;
     }}

Comment: I think I confused you by the way I defined the function as a variable. Edited. Also edited the regex (it wouldn't include words next to punctuation or words at the beginning of the string).

Comment: Or to explain it better, you can define the function (the top part) anywhere, but you have to call it from inside the same scope. So if you define it inside another function, like you have above with `finds()`, you can only use it inside that function (unless you want to use a closure, which you probably don't).

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. it worked and your explanation is very helpful. one more thing, what is alert? is this for JavaScript or on spreadsheet?

Comment: also /\b\w{1,2}\b/g; in language: / is beginning of expression, \b is any digit, \w any alphanumeric expression,{1 2} number 1 to 2, g is ?

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered if you want. `alert()` is a function that is native to the browser, but it may also be available in your spreadsheet app (the documentation would tell you).  `\b` is used to mark off a word boundary (like the beginning and the end of a word. `\w` is any word character (numbers, letters, and underscore). {1,2} is a range. g is a flag indicating you want to look through the whole string, not just stop at the first match. If you want to learn how to do regular expressions I highly recommend [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Comment: Nope, it's a range, so change it to `{1,9}`.